# Combo box is filling with valueMember not with the DisplayMember from DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am filling combo box like this

```
cbDepartment.DataSource = SQLObject.Departments;
            cbDepartment.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cbDepartment.ValueMember = "Id";
```

and data gridview like this

```
EmployeeGrd.DataSource = SQLObject.sp_ViewEmployee();
```

Combo box is filling with another table that is my look up table "Department" it just contain "Name" and "Id" while DataGridView is filled with stored procedure that is coming from another table that just contain "Id" of Department table when I am filling combo box from data grid view it is filling "Id" in combo box,I need to fill "Name" not the "Id" Can any body plz help???

I am filling combo box like this.

```
 comboBox1.SelectedText = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Could you explain why you have the last line of code? How is tis relevant to the question? Everything you have shown looks fine - the combobox column in your datagridview should display the name from property from that datasource. You will probably need to set the DataPropertyName but I don't think that would effect the display.

Comment: Aye whole point of a data source is you don't have to fill the bound control(s) comment out that line, see what happens.

Comment: combobox is ot in grid its external to it I have to fill this combobox from datagrid and last is what I am doing right now but its not fruit full because its giving value member I need to fill combobox with Display member.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sorry I didn't get you...

Comment: Id is not looking odd combobox should be fill with the text("Name") not with the Id,person Cant see Lookup table he need to work on front end and he is blind to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView cells have a property `FormattedValue` which is what you need to use here.

```
comboBox1.SelectedText = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
```